# WebSphere redirect on login drops the domain/host name. WASReqURL missing domain/host name

Tags: webserver, websphere

I am running a WebSphere 8.5.5.3 installation with WebSphere HTTP server in a cluster environment on AIX. I am having a problem of incorrect redirects upon login e.g.:

- User is trying to access http://domain_name/app_name/resource_name
- User is redirected to the login page at http://domain_name/Login.html
- User enters valid credentials
- User is redirected to the incorrect url at http:///app_name/resource_name
- If the user logs in a second time then everything works fine

What am I doing wrong? Have I misconfigured something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8deb461e-d3fe-41e5-9402-52be4ec4dba9 here is the answer:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=203&ca=portall2&uid=swg21259747

Summary:
Create a custom property for WebSphere Global Security:

**Name:** com.ibm.websphere.security.util.fullyQualifiedURL
**Value:** true

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was able to restart the WebSphere application server... but you may need to restart all of WebSphere if restarting just the app server app is not enough.

[image]

[image]